# FaIcon in Flutter has a weird padding / margin

Tags: flutter, user-interface, icons, font-awesome

Is there a way to remove the extra space above and below the FaIcon in Flutter?

There is a Row with a `TextFormField` and a Column with a dollar sign and caretDown icon.

[image]

What I want is to move the icon more up, so that it's right below the dollar sign, but it shows some strange vertical padding, that I don't understand how to remove.

Anybody had the same problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use InputDecoration class with suffix property.

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                          kIsWeb || isTab ? 10 : 5),
                                      hintText: widget.isRemoveMoney
                                          ? "Why?"
                                          : "What’s it for?",
                                      hintStyle: CommonStyles().textStyle(
                                          textColor: colorConstant.colorBDBDBD),
                                      errorStyle: CommonStyles().textStyle(
                                        textColor: colorConstant.colorE86A3D,
                                      ),
                                      suffix: Column(children: [
                                        Icon(Icons.settings),
                                        Icon(Icons.settings)
                                      ],), //add suffix property
                                      errorMaxLines: 2,
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      //OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0))
                                    ),
```